# Pass Chronometer time between activities

Tags: java, android, chronometer

I have this `Chronometer` in my main activity and I want to get the value of this chronometer after the user finished the given task in the mainActivity.class and display it to the next activity (end.class)

**MainActivity.class** snippet:

```
private void showElapsedTime() {

        long timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chrono.getBase();      
            int millis = (int) timeElapsed;
            int seconds = (int) timeElapsed/1000;
            int minutes = seconds/60;

            Toast.makeText(this, "Level1 - Elapsed time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

**end.class**:

```
TextView Set1;      

Set1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.time1);
```

How can I get the chronometer value from the MainActivity.class and display it in my textview in end.class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: Are you get the chronometer time in mainactivity class or not.

Comment: Who initiates the start of `End`? Do you create the intent in `MainActivity` or do you use some other way?

Comment: I know how to pass data between activities, I just don't know how to get the value of the chronometer. I tried Intent and bundle but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Heuster I created intent in MainActivity to move to second activity after the user finishes the task given.

Comment: Chronometer is already declared before the onCreate method.

Comment: @pingboo23 So, if I understand correctly, you already have an intent `i` for `End` and when the user finishes the task, you call `startActivity(i)`? Then, just before that line, add `long timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chrono.getBase();` and `i.putExtra("timeElapsed", timeElapsed)`.

Comment: @Heuster then I'll just set it to the end.class? extract intent and display the value?

Comment: @pingboo23 yes, there you call `getIntent().getExtras().getLong("timeElapsed")` and use it however you like (or simply `getIntent().getLongExtra("timeElapsed", 0L)`)

Comment: @Heuster How can I display `timeElapsed` ? I can't used it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35904/discussion-between-heuster-and-pingboo23)

Comment: `I tried Intent and bundle but it doesn't work`  Of course it works, thousands of developers use it every day.  Your code is the problem but you haven't shown it.

Comment: @Simon I've already shown it in my other post, but didn't resolved it. I create this new post to get new answers.

Comment: I've read both of these posts, and my best advice is to learn how to use the debugger.  It's really easy and if you knew how to use it, you would find this problem in minutes.  NullPointerExceptions are very common and also very easy to solve.

Comment: @Simon already solved my problem by the help of Heuster :)

Answer (score 0):

The setBase() is used to set the time that the count-up timer is in reference to. . You need to hold on to this value somewhere outside the activity, like in the Application class. Whenever your activity has resumes, you setBase() to this reference time.